# Porque eu preciso usar um construtor para criar minha variável style?

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, View} from 'react-native';


class Botao extends Component{

this.style = StyleSheet.create({}); // ESSE CODIGO TA PEDINDO PARA CRIAR UM CONSTRUTOR

render(){
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <View>
                <Text>Clique</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
export default class App extends Component{
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Botao/>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Creio que fora do `construtor` realmente não é uma boa ideia usar o `this`, mas a documentação fala como você pode criar seu ´style´ e importar.
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

O construtor é solicitado devido ao fato de não ser possível declarar variáveis com a palavra-chave `this` fora do mesmo, pois, o método `constructor` é um tipo especial de método para criar e iniciar variáveis, objetos, métodos de uma classe.

Implemente o código abaixo e deverá funcionar.

```
constructor() {
    this.style = StyleSheet.create({});
}
```

Comment: Entendi! No caso, o this não tem a referencia global da classe sem o construtor? Então eu posso tirar o this e criar a variavel normal não? Eu só não entendo o motivo de precisar fazer as declarações dentro do construtor.

Comment: Sim, você pode criar a variável de estilo fora do escopo da classe conforme é mostrado na documentação  [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html).

Answer (score 0):

Eu não poderia fazer assim? Sem o construtor...

```
class Botao extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
           <TouchableOpacity>
                <View>
                    <Text style={this.styles.texto}>Clique</Text>
                </View>
           </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }

    styles = StyleSheet.create({
        texto:{
            fontSize: 60
        }
    }); 

}
```